# How to avoid maxWidth to be the default width?

Tags: xcode, swiftui

I have the following code, I want the maxWidth to not affect the size of the Text when its content has a width less than 150. As you can see in the image, when I set a maxWidth of 150, the Text view starts with that value, but I only want it to be a maximum value, not the initial one.

```swift
var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack(alignment: .firstTextBaseline) {
                Text("text")
                    .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: 150, alignment: .leading)
                    .background(.blue)
                Text("000000")
                Spacer()
                Text("text")
            }
        }
    }
```

[preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RcAW9.png)

I do this because I want that with small texts the numbers are attached to the first Text view, but when the text is large I want a line break as shown in the image.

[preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Baed5.png)

I have tried modifying the frame with maxWidth, and minWidth set to 0, but that also does not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add `fixedSize` *outside* of the `frame` modifier:

```
.frame(maxWidth: 150, alignment: .leading)
.fixedSize()
```

[image]

[image]